# Get the value from a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qlineedit

I have a `QLineEdit` that only allows numbers and I want to get the current value from it. I can't figure out how.

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(this));
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
QString XMAX=ui->lineEdit->text();
xMax=XMAX.toDouble();
```

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
std::stod(ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString());
```

but watch out for the encoding.

Comment: This is better (conserves encoding): std::stod(ui->lineEdit->text().toUtf8());

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ui->leNome->displayText()
```